# Use of parameterized tests with JUnit

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a class where one of the public methods is a  perfect fit for parameterized tests. Also I am reading that you usually keep a correspondence between testcases (a class having multiple methods with @Test annotated methods) and classes in the project. Is it possible somehow to use both Parameterized.class and JUnitCore.class as the runner ? Right now if utilizing Parameterized I can't work out how to setup non-parameterized testing of methods
within the same testcase. I have thought about then creating a Suite wich would then include
the Parameterized test and "regular" ones, but then it seems that to make names meaningful for testcases, I would have to bind the name of the testcase to the name of the method rather then to the class containing the method which seems to be standard way.

For example

```
 public class MyClass {

     public int methodSuitableForParameterizedTest(int m){
         // Implementation
     }

     public int methodForRegularTest(int m) {
         // Implmentation
     }
 }
```

Can I still have a single testcase `TestMyclass` that contains paremeterized testing of the first method as well as non-parameterized testing of the second ?

Comment: Keep in mind that when using a Parameterized test, both the Constructor and also the Collection/List of arrays method are both called by Reflection and are NOT to be called from the test suite class.  Reflection allows the unit test class to call its own constructor by using the static collection method to build the test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite difficult to do, it involves creating your own runner which does both jobs, so I would just stick to the two class solution, one with the parameterized tests and one without.

The problem is twofold, the `@RunWith` annotation on the class and the contructor. For a parameterized test, you need `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` and a constructor with arguments. For a standard test, the constructor has no parameters. And JUnit checks that a particular class has only one constructor. You can do this by creating another runner, but it's not simple.

I would recommend in this case having two test classes.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Just annoying not being able to keep the the one test-case per class structure.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is trivial to do with TestNG's data providers, which allows you to have as many parameterized test methods and data providers in a class as you want, but which also passes these parameters directly into your test method...  http://testng.org

Comment: Thanks Cedric. This might be the last nod at TestNG I needed before convincing myself that it is time to move on from JUnit.

Comment: If you ever take the step, Eclipse will help you migrate your entire project with just a few clicks. It's a one-time thing, so even if you're not an Eclipse user, it might be worth running it just for the migration.

Answer (score 1):

recently i started [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) project. it lets you write:

```
@TestWith({
   "25 USD",
   "38 GBP",
   "null"
})
public void testMethod(Money money) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: i like zohhak, but would rather use Spock. even simpler.